# What would be the best way to design following scenario

Tags: ooad

The scenario is :

A man can walk .
A Superman can walk and fly
A Spiderman can walk and crawl .

What would be the best design pattern for this .

Comment: Looks like simple inheritance to me.

Comment: what else can we do ? inheritance will cause us to cast it to call appropriate method .

Comment: Depends on the language you're using. No cast required in Java.

Comment: @verbose-mode can you explain a bit . would be very helpful .

Answer (score 1):

I would just use an interface for each ability

```
interface ICanWalk
{ 
    ///walk methods
}

interface ICanFly
{
    //fly methods
}

interface ICanCrawl
{
    //crawl methods
}
```

and then have concrete classes

```
Man: ICanWalk 
Superman : ICanWalk, ICanFly
Spiderman : ICanWalk, ICanCrawl
```

To be honest without more details its quite hard to speculate

Comment: don't you think it will be duplicate code , because Superman and SpiderMan has to implement Walk again .

Comment: if the implementation is the same then yes you will duplicate. In that case create a base class or delegate to a helper `ManWalker` class. But that is a different question from what you asked.